# how to output html with jquery without appending to element?

Tags: jquery

I would like to output the html code below without appending it to any element.
is this possible.I need to do that because the jquery plugin i'm using needs to have the clean html below
Any ideas .
Thanks

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: "{}",
    url:"page.aspx/getData",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

      if (data.hasOwnProperty("d"))
        DoSomething(data.d);
      else
        DoSomething(data);
    }
 });



function DoSomething(msg) {
   var SComms = msg;
   alert(msg);
 }
```

and html

```
    <blockquote>
        <p>Ut eu consectetur nisi. Praesent facilisis diam nec sapien gravida non mattis justo imperdiet. Vestibulum nisl urna, euismod sit amet congue at, bibendum non risus.</p>
        <cite>&ndash; Quote Author (Quote #1)</cite>
    </blockquote>
```

Comment: If you don't want to append it to any element, then where do you want it outputted? Don't really understand your question. It would have to be appended to an element to be visible, unless you just want to `alert` it.

Comment: what do you mean by "output" ? where do you want to output ?

Comment: Sorry but your question conflicts itself. Output the HTML means appending it to *something* otherwise it won't be output. Unless you mean output into new browser window? Into frame? Printer?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Everything you see on web page is DOM element. If you want to display something, just append to appropriate element. Alternatively you could use loging to console.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least, you have to append the output to `body`, `html`, or `document` to see it in a browser. Of course, you can output it as a Javascript-alert, but I strongly discourage the usage of `alert();`.

#### EDIT 1

You can add the output to a variable.

```
var globalVariable = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   data: "{}",
   url:"page.aspx/getData",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      if (data.hasOwnProperty("d"))
         DoSomething(data.d);
      else
         DoSomething(data);
   }
});

function DoSomething(msg) {
   var SComms = msg;
   globalVariable = SComms;
}
```

If you do it like this, you can access the variable later on. It is important however that you declare it outside of the `ready()` method or else the value is lost because it goes out of [scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)).

Comment: Thanks guys.OK its not possible.
So i reckon there are 2 ways i can get the output i want neither i create the element on the client side or do it in the code and then have to append it to an element later. Is this right.? If yes what do i need to do to do it on the client side?
Would i have to return the objects on the client side? Trying using page method with no success.

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem, it's seem that jQuery template is based on append... (See source)
For example this don't work

```
$.template('navTpl', '<ul>{{html li}}</ul>');
$.template('navItemTpl', '<li>${titre}</li>');

var navItemTplValue = [
    {titre: 'photos'},
    {titre: 'films'},
    {titre: 'musiques'}
];
var navItemTplHtml = $.tmpl('navItemTpl', navItemTplValue);

var navTplValue = {li: navItemTplHtml}; // FAIL, even with navItemTplHtml.html()
var navTpl = $.tmpl('navTpl', navTplValue).appendTo('body');
```

Sample test here : http://jsfiddle.net/molokoloco/wtHeX/